# Cocos2D-js прозрачная маска для тайлов

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, cocos2d

Пробую изометрию с Cocos2D-JS. Столкнулся с проблеммой стен. Когда персонаж заходит за стену, его изображение желательно бы показать) На примере fallout2 там это было реализовано через альфа маску, которая накладывалась на тайлы и создавала прозрачную область

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы решили эту проблему?

Comment: Нет. Я забил на cocos и работу с графикой вообще